# What's the function of following prepositional phrase in the sentence?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, adjectivals

X lodge complaints **against y**.

Does **against y** is an adjectival prepositional phrase describing the words "complaints"?

Comment: Prepositional phrase can act as a adjectival prepositional phrase..

Comment: In your example "complaints against y" means that x is complaining about something that x has done or supplied etc.

Comment: When a prepositional phrase modifies a noun, pronoun, gerund, or noun phrase (all of which function grammatically as nouns), it is considered to function as an adjective within the sentence.

Comment: Now listen up @Sam No it isn't. It is considered to function as a **modifier**. 'Adjective' is **not** a function. In any case, the PP "against y" is not a Modifier but a Complement.

Comment: Prepositional phrases function as either adjectives modifying nouns or adverbs modifying verbs, how it can be a complement????

Comment: It answers the question what kind of of complaints he lodge? ➡ Complaints against y.

Answer (score 0):

> *X lodges / lodged complaints against y.*

"Against" is a preposition, so "against y" must be a preposition phrase. Its function is that of complement".

It qualifies as a complement, as opposed to a modifier, because it is licensed (specifically required or permitted) by the verb "lodges /lodged".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's an adjectival prepositional phrase describing "complaints." The noun "complaint" selects the preposition "against" and gives it a specific meaning (indicating the target of the complaint). Hence, in BillJ's terminology (which comes from Huddleston & Pullum (2002)), it is classified as a complement of that noun, rather than a modifier.